# HTML links not working in Firefox but work fine in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, html, firefox

Some children of a link-enabled DIV do not work in Firefox, though they work fine in Chrome.

See a live example at [www.tekiki.com](http://www.tekiki.com). Try clicking on the text area of the first app listed. It won't work. You can, however, click on the icon even though both the text and the icon belong to the same parent link.

We tried other suggestions from StackOverflow, including setting `overflow:hidden` and clearing floats, but none seem to work.

We're testing on Firefox 24.

Help?

**HTML:**

```
<a class="app_box click_drop" href="/itunes-store/apps/free-apps/app/runtastic-road-bike-pro-gps-cycling-computer-tracker?itunes-store-id=468429333" itunes_id="468429333" path="/36/6013/468429333">
            <div class="icon_box">
                <div class="icon" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/4b/91/03/4b910379-2983-22be-358c-0c894ca82216/mzl.izwihsdx.256x256-75.jpg&quot;);"></div>
            </div>      
            <div class="caption_box">
                <div class="details_box">
                    <div class="name">Runtastic Road Bike PRO GPS Cycling Computer &amp; Tracker</div>                  
                    <div class="desc_box">
                        <div class="desc text">“Free today with ‘App of the Day’. 

Download ‘App of the Day’, and every day discover one paid app absolutely free!”

4.5+ Rating, TechCrunch, Mashable, NYTimes and others are raving about Runtastic... Find out why &amp; download...</div>
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="ratings_box">
                        <div class="avg_rating" style="background-position: 0px -91px;"></div> <span class="num_ratings">2040</span>                            
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="price_box" style="display: block;">                     
                        <span class="cur_price">Free</span> <span class="old_price">$4.99</span> <span style="display:none" class="sponsored">Sponsored</span>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.page_list .app_box:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.page_list .list a {
    color: #5C5C5C;
}
.page_list .app_box {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url("/images/dandy/caption_bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    margin: 25px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
a {
    color: #5E87B0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `z-index` issue that is preventing it from being linked.

Use `z-index: -1` on `#bg_graphics` for it to work.

**For Instance,**

```
#bg_graphics {
    background: url("/images/web/bg_graphics.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 465px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -900px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 1800px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: you don't happen to know why "moz-box-pack:justify" isn't working on this page (http://www.tekiki.com/itunes-store/apps/free-apps/all) do you? (the numbers should be right-aligned.)

Comment: Why are you using which is only restricted to firefox? - @Crashalot

Comment: we have it also for other browsers, but for some reason the mozilla version isn't working. should we be using something else? "display:box" and "box-pack:justify" fail in firefox.

Comment: I checked and it is working fine on `.page_list .category_box` - @Crashalot

Comment: moz-box-pack - @Crashalot

Comment: hmm, the number is not right aligned for us ... it is for you? which firefox are you using?

Comment: hmm, we're on 25.0, but the numbers still appear not right aligned as seen in this screen shot: http://imgur.com/KeBX0ZX. maybe it's fixed in 25.0.1? if you have no other suggestions, thanks, anyway!

Comment: make two span and align one to left and the numbers to right and it will work the way you want. - @Crashalot

Answer (score 0):

Try by applying `z-index` higher, it works.

```
#page_box {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the speedy response! i wish i could award you both the question, but in fairness, nathan lee barely beat you to a response. thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add `z-index: -1;` to `#bg_graphics`

or

Add `z-index: 9999;` to `#page_box`